# Merging and reshaping sheets without for loop in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to merge some data using Excel or VBA but struggle to do so without using for loops, which are very slow given the number of rows.

Let Sheet1 and Sheet2 be two sheets which both have common keys `key1`, `key2`, etc. columns identifying individuals.

```
Sheet1 :
A    |B    |C    |D       |E    |F
Key1 |Key2 |Key3 |Feature |2015 |2016
X1   |Y1   |Z1   |F1      |   1 |   2
X1   |Y1   |Z1   |F2      |  10 |  30
X1   |Y1   |Z1   |F3      |   3 |   4 
X2   |Y1   |Z2   |F1      |   2 |   1
X2   |Y1   |Z2   |F2      |   5 |   8
X2   |Y1   |Z2   |F3      |   2 |   2
X1   |Y3   |Z2   |F1      |  12 |   9
X1   |Y3   |Z2   |F2      |   7 |   1
X1   |Y3   |Z2   |F3      |   4 |   4
```

```
Sheet2 :
A    |B    |C    |D          |E          |F
Key1 |Key2 |Key3 |01-01-2015 |02-01-2015 |01-01-2016
X1   |Y1   |Z1   |        11 |        12 |         8
X2   |Y1   |Z2   |        52 |        21 |         2
X1   |Y3   |Z2   |        29 |        59 |         5
```

I'd like to make a function MYFUN(RangeS1, RangeS2, [Rangefilter, Valuefilter]), which would do the sumproduct of feature `F3` of each individuals from Sheet1 with its respective value from Sheet2.
Additionally, it would take optional argument allowing to filter over individuals.

Thus, =MYFUN(Sheet1!E2:E10, Sheet2!E2:E4) would return 3x12+2x21+4x59.

Likewise =MYFUN(Sheet1!E2:E10, Sheet2!E2:E4, Sheet2!B2:B4, "Y3") would return 4x59.

Comment: "without using for loops, which are very slow given the number of rows" - there's no reason that needs to be slow if you first read the source data into arrays

Comment: Oh really, so If I juste save my range in an object within vba, it will be quicker ?
e.g. saving myrange in a range object before something like: For Each c In myrange.Rows

Comment: No more like `Dim arr: arr = myRange.Value` then loop over `arr` instead of looping over `myRange`.  If you need more specific advice then consider posting some of your "slow" VBA and asking for help with making it faster.

Comment: Alright, I'll make a try first and come back then for help. Thank you very much.

Comment: I guess you could you PowerQuery to do that for you.